# Pass Thru from Access To SQL Assistant with looping variable

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access-2010, teradata

I am using Access 2010 to create a pass thru query to Teradata 14 SQL assistant. I have a VBA module that modifies the SQL in a query that is then passed to the Teradata SQL assistant. This process works fine. My problem is with VBA coding the following problem which I concede I am week at.

I Have two tables in my access database that each have one column of data called ITEMS. I union them together with a query called qryUNION_ITEMS to get an item list. What I want to do is pass this item list into a variable in VBA to include in my SQL code.

Example of final code that gets passed from VBA to an Access query that I am looking to accomplish...

```
CREATE TABLE TD271 AS (SELECT INVOICE, DATE, ITEM_NUMBER, ITEM_QUANTITY
FROM DETAIL_TABLE
WHERE ITEM_NUMBER IN(00001, 00002, 13579, 24680, 13794))
WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX I0002PI (INVOICE, DATE)
```

Here is my VBA code as I have it now.

from VBA code where TempItemNumber is the variable.

```
CREATE TABLE TD271 AS (SELECT INVOICE, DATE, ITEM_NUMBER, ITEM_QUANTITY 
FROM DETAIL_TABLE
WHERE ITEM_NUMBER IN(" & TempItemNumber & "))
WITH DATA PRIMARY INDEX I0002PI (INVOICE, DATE)
```

The item list can be a couple of items or a hundred. I need to take the items from my union query qryUNION_ITEMS and add them to the code above placing a comma after each item). I would think some sort of loop to build the item list to the TempItemNumber variable would accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just push the results of your union query to a table in Teradata?  Then just use that as a sub-select Something like:

```
SELECT INVOICE, DATE, ITEM_NUMBER, ITEM_QUANTITY 
FROM DETAIL_TABLE
WHERE ITEM_NUMBER IN
(select distinct item_number from <your new table>)
```

Comment: Teradata will not recognize tables and queries from Access. You need to put the data into SQL code and then run that code from Access using a pass thru query.  I agree that would be the easiest way but SQL assistant will not recognize Access Table and Query objects.